# Can SVG <animate> tags' values attribute reference CSS variables?

Tags: html, svg, cross-browser, svg-animate

Using `values="var(--color1);var(--color2)"` in an SVG `<animate>` tag works in Firefox but not Chrome (see the snippet below).  Is there a way to make it work in Chrome?

```css
:root {
    --color1: #7F0000;
    --color2: #007F00;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100">
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="25" fill="var(--color1)">
        <animate attributeName="fill" dur="3s" values="var(--color1);var(--color2);var(--color1)" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Chrome is open source. Download the source code and submit a patch to fix it I guess.

Comment: Interesting side observation: if you exchange one of the `var()` in the list with a known color value, you can see the animation is actually running - it's just that the color value is treated as invalid and exchanged for the default black.

Comment: @Robert Longson @ccprog: why do css variables work as SVG attribute values at all? Within a `style` attribute – sure – and also handy but I haven't found any w3 spec documentation.

Comment: @herrstrietzel https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/#ValuesAttribute doesn't mention CSS variables. Fundamentally you need to identify whether something is a CSS property though and for that you run either run a CSS parser on it and ask it whether it is or not, or you could have some list of CSS Properties. It seems Firefox does the former and Chrome does the latter.

Comment: @herrstrietzel At least it's found its way into the W3C [test suite](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/blob/master/css/css-variables/variable-presentation-attribute.html) for CSS Variables.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest *workaround* is a native JavaScript Web Component

*something* like:
`getComputedStyle(this).getPropertyValue("--color1")` to read CSS values

```js
customElements.define("svg-circle", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.style.display = "inline-block";
    let c1 = this.getAttribute("color1") || "lightgoldenrodyellow";
    let c2 = this.getAttribute("color2") || "rebeccapurple";
    this.innerHTML = `<svg width="180" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100">
    <circle r="49">
     <animate attributeName="fill" dur="3s" values="${c1};${c2};${c1}" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle></svg>`;
  }
});
```

```html
<svg-circle></svg-circle>
<svg-circle color1="gold"></svg-circle>
<svg-circle color1="red" color2="green"></svg-circle>
```

Comment: No, the easiest workaround would be a CSS @keyframes animation.

Comment: Add is as answer so OP can mark it. 3 different circles please

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the SMIL animation with an animation done with [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API).

```js
const circle01 = document.getElementById('circle');

var circleKeyframes = new KeyframeEffect(
  circle01, [{
      fill: 'var(--color1)'
    },
    {
      fill: 'var(--color2)'
    }
  ], {
    duration: 3000,
    iterations: Infinity
  }
);

var a1 = new Animation(circleKeyframes, document.timeline);
a1.play();
```

```css
:root {
  --color1: #7F0000;
  --color2: #007F00;
}

circle {
  fill: var(--color1);
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100">
  <circle id="circle" cx="0" cy="0" r="25" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the easiest way to do this is with pure CSS. I added a "id" attribute to the circle so we can target it with a CSS selector. I then used CSS keyframes and animation to add the color change effect. I also switched the svg fill attribute out for a CSS style fill so we can avoid the weirdness of accessing CSS var() outside of CSS.

```css
:root {
    --color1:#7F0000;
    --color2:#007F00;
}
#aCircle{
    animation:test 3s linear 0s infinite;
}
@keyframes test{
    0% {fill:var(--color1);}
    50% {fill:var(--color2);}
    100% {fill:var(--color1);}
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100">
    <circle id="aCircle" cx="0" cy="0" r="25" style="fill:var(--color1);"/>
</svg>
```